# Wrapping multiple rows in html with twig

Tags: php, html, twig, rows

So I'm using twig to render a bunch of entities in an array to the page and I'm wondering if it's possible to wrap each chunk of them in html?

For example, if I have 100 entities, and I want to wrap every 10 in a div with class "page", is this possible with twig or do I need something else?

I've been playing around with cycle, modulus etc but cant figure it out. Any suggestions?

I am currently using a for loop to put them onto the page, and trying to figure out how to wrap groups of them with html.

Comment: Have a look at `batch` - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html

Comment: Or you can add `if..else` statement using `loop.index` variable: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Comment: Thanks guys - very useful stuff. Add an answer and Ill accept it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `batch` filter for this. From `Twig` [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html):

> The batch filter "batches" items by returning a list of lists with the
>   given number of items. A second parameter can be provided and used to
>   fill in missing items:

```
{% set items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] %}

<table>
{% for row in items|batch(3, 'No item') %}
    <tr>
        {% for column in row %}
            <td>{{ column }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Or even you can use simple `if..else` statement using `loop.index` [variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

```
{% set items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] %}

<table>
{% for row in items %}
    {% if loop.index % 3 == 1 %}
    <tr>
    {% endif %}
        <td>{{ row }}</td>
    {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 or loop.last %}
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

As you can see using `batch` is more clear.